# How to check if a UserControl is running?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an `UserControl` that can be opened from the `Main` application through a `Button`. The same `UserControl` is available in another `App`, this `second` app, only display the window of the `UserControl`. Now I need to know if this control was already started from the `MainApplication`, if yes, then I need to prevent starting the `second` app.

I actually tried two "solutions":

**1. Using the process**

```
 Process current = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

 foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName(current.ProcessName))
 {
     if (p.Id != current.Id)
     {
       break;
     }
 }
```

this code check if the Process is already in execution. That solution does not  work 'cause when I start the `UserControl` from the `Main` app, and then run the `second` app, I have two instance of `UserControl`.

**2. Using Mutex**

```
 bool createdNew;

 _mutex = new Mutex(true, "UserControlName", out createdNew);

 if (!createdNew)
 {
    //Check for other instance
    Process current = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

    foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName(current.ProcessName))
    {
       if (p.Id != current.Id)
       {
          break;
       }
    }

    return true;
 }
 else
 {
     _mutex?.Close();
     return false;
 }
```

this solution only work if I run the `UserControl` from the `Main` app, in particular this will not show the `UserControl` again, anyway, if I run this from the `second` app, then I get two instance of the `UserControl`.

How can I handle this?

**UPDATE**

All the code I posted was added inside the `MainWindow` constructor, if you want test this you need only to paste the code inside the constructor, that's it.

Comment: You have to post more information see also [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is your check encapsulated in a method? Where do you use this check? Can you post minimal example which can reproduce the issue?

Comment: UserControl is something which looks nicely on the screen and allow the app to receive user interactions. What does the concept "UserControl was started and is running" mean?

Comment: @Ash I mean for "started" in this case `displayed`, the usercontrol in this case is an application compiled in a dll

Comment: then probably control should create Mutex when `Loaded` and release it when it is Unloaded or app is closed. then whoever is interested may check Mutext existance